# The probability of at least 2 visits in a certain state before reaching another state

Tags: probability, markov-chains

In a Markov chain, we have four states: $0, 1, 2, 3$.
The transition matrix is 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 2/3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1/3 & 0 & 2/3\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
The initial state is $1$, and we need to find the probability that $0$ is visited  **at least** twice before reaching $3$ (which is "game over": an absorbing state).

My solution if the following:
Define $P_{i v}$ as the probability to visit $0$ at least $v$ times before reaching $3$, given that the current state is $i$ (not including $i$ if it happends to be $0$).

Then we can use the law of total probability to obtain:
$$
{\left\{\begin{matrix}
P_{12}=\frac{2}{3}P_{22}+\frac{1}{3}P_{01}\\ 
P_{22}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 0+\frac{1}{3}P_{12}\\ 
P_{01}=\frac{2}{3}P_{11}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1\\ 
P_{11}=\frac{2}{3}P_{21}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1\\ 
P_{21}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 0+\frac{1}{3}P_{11}\\
\end{matrix}\right.}
$$
Which has the solution:
$$
{\left\{\begin{matrix}
P_{12}=13/49\\ 
P_{22}=13/147\\ 
P_{01}=13/21\\ 
P_{11}=3/7\\ 
P_{21}=1/7\\
\end{matrix}\right.}
$$
so the answer seems to be $13/49$. 
However, the solution attached (which seems to never be wrong) says that the answer is $95/243$.
So I have two questions:

1. Could someone please verify my solution?
2. Does someone know a shorter solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Doing a computation by hand, I also get a solution $13/49$.

Comment: You mean by solving the equation system?

Comment: My approach was: (1) eliminate state $2$, and say that we can go from $1$ to $3$ with probability $4/9$ and from $1$ to $1$ with probability $2/9$; (2) eliminate the self-loop in state $1$, so that conditioned on leaving state $1$, you either go to $0$ (with probability $3/7$) or to $3$ (with probability $4/7$); (3) state $3$ finally "wins" with probability $4/7 + 3/7 \cdot 2/3 \cdot 4/7$ (directly or one visit to $0$). Finally $1 - (4/7 + 3/7 \cdot 2/3 \cdot 4/7) = 13/49$.

Comment: Nice method! Thank you, that helped